# How to get BottomSheet progress in Android Jetpack Compose Material 3?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In the below Material Design version

**implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.3'**

i was able to get the progress as shown below

```
rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState().bottomSheetState.progress
```

but in Compose Material 3 am not able to get the progress

**implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha03'**

```
rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState().bottomSheetState.progress
```

here for progress its says **Unresolved reference: progress**

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9pmJ.png)

please help me to solve this.